# Linear independence between functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve some exercises on the linear independence between functions and in most of them we use the "trick" of deriving. I would like to know why, if there is a theorem, a proposition or a simple consideration about function that I missed in order to explein this method.
For example:
Let $\\f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=e^{2x}$ we suppose  $\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}=0$.
Deriving we have $\lambda_1e^x+2\lambda_2e^{2x}=0$.
Subtracting the first to the second $\lambda_2e^{2x}=0$ so $\lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_1=0$

Comment: What is this trick of deriving?

Comment: I made an example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is notable that proving independence using your differentiation trick is equivalent to considering the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of the function.

Second, here is a justification of this method as you have presented it. The only fact being used here is the following:

> **Claim:** If two differentiable functions $f,g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ satisfy $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$, then they also satisfy $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for all $x$.

I'd say that with the statement written in the above form, there is really nothing to prove: if $f$ and $g$ are the same function, then they have the same derivative. With that established, we begin with your equation
$$
\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}=0.
$$
Keep in mind that, since we are determining whether the functions $e^{x},e^{2x}$ are linearly independent, the above should be interpreted as stating that $\lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}=0$ holds for all $x \in \Bbb R$. In other words, if we define two functions $f,g$ by $f(x) = \lambda_1e^x+\lambda_2e^{2x}$ and $g(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Now, since $f'(x) = \lambda_1e^x+2\lambda_2e^{2x}$ and $g'(x) = 0$, it follows that the new equation
$$
f'(x) = g'(x) \implies \lambda_1e^x+2\lambda_2e^{2x} = 0
$$
holds for all $x$.

Comment: And if I have ${2t, \cos(t)}$ considering the Wronskian of the functions I have $-t\sin(t)-2\cos(t)=0$ then what I have to do?

Comment: @Sandrin Because the Wronskian that you computed is not the zero function (i.e. the equation that you wrote is not true for all $t$), you can conclude that $2t$ and $\cos(t)$ must be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sin(2x)$, $g(x)=\sin x \cos x$ are linearly dependent as $f(x)=k g(x), \forall x \in R$, here $k$ is a constant constant independent of $x$. Two analytic (diferentiable) functions $f(x), g(x)$ are linearly
dependent if $$W(x)=\left|\begin{matrix} f(x) & g(x) \\ f'(x) & g'(x) \end{matrix}\right|=0.$$ Linearly independent if this quantity called Wronslian is non-zero.

Three analytic functions are linearly dependent if one can be written as a linear sum of other twp like $f(x)=a g(x)+ b h(x)$, $\forall$ real values of $x$ where $a,b$ are independent of $x$. For example $\sin x, \cos x, 1$  are linearly independent because they may be related linearly only for some values of $x$ (the relationship is an equation rather than an isentity). But $\sin^2 x, \cos^2 x, 1$ are linearly dependent. Three functions $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ are linearly independent if
$$W(x)=\left|\begin{matrix} f(x) & g(x) & h(x) \\ f'(x) & g'(x) & h'(x) \\ f''(x) & g''(x) & h''(x)\end{matrix}\right|\ne 0.$$
For $n$ functions the Wronskian is $W(x)$ is $n \times n$ determinant using all derivative up to $n$.

Comment: It is **not** true that if $W(x) = 0$, then the functions are linearly dependent. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606573/81360) for a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks I have now added the word analytic in my edit.